# On the Windows platform when calling getPicture() with "sourceType" of "PHOTOLIBRARY" or "SAVEDPHOTOALBUM" it returns "Not supported" error

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I'm trying to make a app where you have to select a image from photo gallery. I’m trying to realize this by using the Cordova Camera plugin, but I work also with AngularJS.

The problem is when I’m using the plugin on the Windows platform and calling getPicture() with "sourceType" of "PHOTOLIBRARY" or "SAVEDPHOTOALBUM" it returns "Not supported" error. But the plugin documentation says that Windows is supported.

**Camera plugin:**
Version:0.3.6
- Plugin ID: org.apache.cordova.camera

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
 <ons-template id="page1.html">
    <ons-page ng-controller="page1">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left">
                <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
                    <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
                </ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
            <div class="center">Page 1</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
         <button ng-click="GetPhoto()">Take Photo</button>
        <img id="img1"/>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

**AngularJS**

```
app.controller('page1', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.GetPhoto = function () {
       navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail,
        {
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        });
    function onSuccess(imageData) {
        var imgsrc = document.getelementbyid("img1");             
        imgsrc.src = imageuri;
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        if (appConstants.debug) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }
    }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found an answer on my question. I install a other camera plugin than the standard plugin of Visual Studio.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera